# Grunt (keep-alive) does not exit after the node process ends

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

```
Running "express-keepalive" task
[::ffff:xx.xx.xx.xx] CONNECTED
Caught exception: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:983:19)
```

But even after this the grunt process keep running. I have set `grunt serve:dist` to run as an upstart job but **it won't respawn till the grunt process ends.** I am catching all process errors and making sure the node process exits.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
      console.log('Caught exception: ' + err);
      console.log(err.stack);
      process.exit(1);
});
```

A `ps aux` returns that there are no node process running.

Comment: Why have you opted for `exit` instead of `kill`?

Answer (score 1):

From the node documentation on `uncaughtException`:

> Note that uncaughtException is a very crude mechanism for exception
>   handling.
>
> Don't use it, use [domains](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) instead. If you do use it, restart your
>   application after every unhandled exception!
>
> Do not use it as the node.js equivalent of On Error Resume Next. An
>   unhandled exception means your application - and by extension node.js
>   itself - is in an undefined state. Blindly resuming means anything
>   could happen.
>
> Think of resuming as pulling the power cord when you are upgrading
>   your system. Nine out of ten times nothing happens - but the 10th
>   time, your system is bust.
>
> You have been warned.